# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get external storage files directory Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I want to download file to public dir, it works well when sdcard is avaialble but gives me above error when sdcard is not avaiable. I do checking of sdcard.
I want to save files to `DIRECTORY_MUSIC` which is public by default. But the line `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()`  gives me above error.

Here is the code so far I have written

```
File dir = new File(Environment
                .DIRECTORY_MUSIC + "/" + DIR_NAME + "/");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            // create dir for first time
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "first time created dir");
            dir.mkdir();
        }

        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri songLink = Uri.parse(streamUrl);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(songLink);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMimeType("audio/mp3")
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(v.getContext(), dir.getAbsolutePath(),
                        File.separator + DIR_NAME + File.separator + title);

        dm.enqueue(request);
```

What changes should I do to save file in that dir

I want to save music file which I am downloading from an url and saving to public music directory so that music player will find that file

> My question is how Whatsapp make WhatsApp audio folder and download the whatsapp audios to that dir. For phones with SD card I can do this but I fail when there's no SD card in phone. How it is done ?

Comment: `dir.mkdir();`. You should check the return value. Or check again if the directory exists after that. And not continue if it does not.

Comment: There is no data directory in external files dir. Nor are you creating that directory. What do you have in mind exactly concerning the final path? So about which dir are you talking?

Comment: `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(v.getContext(), dir.getAbsolutePath(),
                        File.separator + DIR_NAME + File.separator + title);`. Please tell in your post the exact values of the used parameters. We cannot see what those paths are. (In your post. Not in a comment). Also the exact path of the dir you tried to create.

Comment: `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir`. ?? What would that have to do with a music directory?

Comment: Has DownloadManager a different  concept of 'external files dir'  than we?

Comment: @greenapps `dir.mkdir()` is always created... i mean that log statement prints always...why is this so ?

Comment: `Log.d(LOG_TAG, "first time created dir");`. That is a nonsense statement. Change to `Log.d(LOG_TAG, "dir does not exist: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());`.p

Comment: After that read my first comment again.

Answer (score 0):

To save download file in public directory:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, filename);
```

This method throws:

> Throws
>   IllegalStateException
>   If the external storage directory cannot be found or create

So you must check if external storage is writable before use.

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also requires permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

[More info](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: the method returns false... so I cant download file to public dir?

Comment: You can test it :D
But I think it's impossible. Let's show message request user insert External storage or stop unmount External storage (when plug usb cable to computer, External storage is unmout)